# Unix redact data

Tags: unix, awk, sed, masking

I want to mask only the 2nd column of the data.

Input:

```
 First_name,second_name,phone_number
 ram,prakash,96174535
 hari,pallavi,98888234
 anurag,aakash,82783784
```

Output Expected:

```
 First_name,second_name,phone_number
 ram,*******,96174535
 hari,*******,98888234
 anurag,******,82783784
```

Comment: Vinay, in your expected output you used a number of asterisks that is equal to the length of "second_name".  Is this your requested behavior or, as assumed in some answers, you can accept a fixed number of asterisks?  I have to add that, if you want to obfuscate the data, a fixed number of asterisks could be a better choice.

Comment: * should be based on length of that field.

Comment: Changing your question in a fundamental way that invalidates *all* current answers is considered bad form. A new question should be asked as a new question.

Comment: @paxdiablo To be fair, Vinay has always used 7 stars or 6 stars in different lines, according to surname's length, starting from the 1st version (see edit history) of their question.  You may say that the answer was poorly written, exactly what you expect  from someone that asks their 1st question, but I see no need for the term _bad form_ in this context.

Comment: @gboffi, the attempted change was from masking field two only to masking fields two and four (a change I rolled back since it invalidated all answers) - that was the fundamental change I was referring to (and I probably should have made it clearer), not the number of characters in the replacement text.

Comment: @paxdiablo Field no.4! 1: name, 2:surname, 3: phone no. and 4: ? OK, the OP is rather naive... sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed` program will do this just fine:

```
sed '2,$s/,[^,]*,/,*****,/'
```

The `2,$` only operates on lines 2 through to the end of the file (to leave the header line alone) and the substitute command `s/,[^,]*,/,*****,/` will replace anything between the first and second comma with the mask `*****`.

---

Note that I've specifically used a *fixed* number of asterisks in the replacement string. Whether you're hiding passwords or anonymising data (as seems to be the case here), you don't want to leak *any* information, including the size of the names being replaced.

---

If you *really* want to use the same number of characters as in the original data, and you also want to cater for the possibility of replacing multiple fields, you can use something like:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}NR==1{print;next}{gsub(/./,"*",$2);gsub(/./,"*",$4);print}'
```

This will also leave the first line untouched but will anonymise columns two and four (albeit with the information leakage previously mentioned):

```
echo 'First_name,second_name,phone_number,other
ram,prakash,96174535,abc
hari,pallavi,98888234,def
anurag,aakash,82783784,g
bob,santamaria,124,xyzzy' | awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}NR==1{print;next}{gsub(/./,"*",$2);gsub(/./,"*",$4);print}'

First_name,second_name,phone_number,other
ram,*******,96174535,***
hari,*******,98888234,***
anurag,******,82783784,*
bob,**********,124,*****
```

Doing multiple columns with *full* anonymising would entail using `$2="*****"` rather than the `gsub` (for both columns of course).

Comment: You give the reason why you changed from OP request, using a fixed replacement string. Upvoted

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk. Using `gsub` to replace every char in `$2` with an `*`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{gsub(/./,"*",$2)}1' file
First_name,second_name,phone_number
ram,*******,96174535
hari,*******,98888234
anurag,******,82783784
```

Comment: hi james , i want to mask 2nd and 4th columns

Comment: @vinay24 You just have 3 columns, the 4th one is automatically masked, isn't it?

Comment: If you want to mask the fourth also, add `;gsub(/./,"*",$4)` after the first `gsub`, ie. `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{gsub(/./,"*",$2);gsub(/./,"*",$4)}1' file`

Answer (score 0):

try following too once and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1{$2="*******"} 1' OFS=,   Input_file
```